# How to Listen on Host Localhost With Docker Desktop on MacOS

Tags: macos, docker, networking

I'm running a special-purpose web server inside a container. The host is a Mac running Docker  Desktop. I need the web server to be accessible only from a web browser running on my Macbook.

If I use port-mapping (e.g. -p 80:80), the web server is available via the Mac's 127.0.0.1, but it also listens on the Mac's IP address, and that's not acceptable in this case.

If this were not Docker, I'd tell the web server to listen on 127.0.0.1. But this is not reachable from outside the container.

How can I run a web server in a container on Docker for Mac, and have it listen only on the Mac's localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Piece of cake... Has nothing to do with the peculiarities of Docker for Mac. Put this in docker-compose.yml

EXPOSE the port in Dockerfile. Put this in docker-compose.yml

```
network_mode: "bridge"
ports:
  - "127.0.0.1:80:80"
```

(substituting your ports for 80).

By using bridge networking, your container will have access to all host IPs. Specifying the IP in the "ports" maps only to the host IP specified.